# compare multiple matrices matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare

I have multiple matrices of the same size and want to compare them.
As a result I need a matrix which gives me the biggest of the 3 for every value.

I will clarify what i mean with an example:

I have 3 matrices with data of 3 persons.

I would like to compare these 3 and get a matrix as result.

In that matrix every cell/value should be the name of the matrix who had the highest value for that cell. So if in the 3 matrices the first value (1 colum, 1 row) is accordingly `2, 5, 8` the first value of the result matrix should be `3` (or the name of the 3 matrix).

Answer (score 5):

If the three matrices are A, B, C, do this:

```
[~, M] = max(cat(3,A,B,C),[],3);
```

It creates a 3D "matrix" and maximizes across the third dimension.

Comment: this gives me the highest value, but as I understand, he (or she) is asking for the position...

Comment: +1: I didnt know about that you can get the index as the second argument

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate them on the 3rd dimension, and the use the SECOND output from max to get exactly what you want

```
A = rand(3,3);
B = rand(3,3);
C = rand(3,3);

D = cat(3, A, B, C)

[~, Solution] = max(D, [], 3)
```

e.g.:

```
D =

ans(:,:,1) =

   0.70101   0.31706   0.83874
   0.89421   0.33783   0.55681
   0.68520   0.11697   0.45631

ans(:,:,2) =

   0.268715   0.213200   0.124450
   0.869847   0.999649   0.153353
   0.345447   0.023523   0.338099

ans(:,:,3) =

   0.216665   0.297900   0.604734
   0.103340   0.767206   0.660668
   0.127052   0.430861   0.021584

Solution =

   1   1   1
   1   2   3
   1   3   1
```

Comment: @user2661122 no problem and welcome to SO. If the answer is correct you should accept it by clicking the outline of the tick mark in the top left of the question. Also if you find an answer helpful, you can also give it an upvote by click the upward pointing triangle also in the top left.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**
As I did not know about the second argument of the max-function, here is what you should NOT use:

**old**
Well, quick&dirty:

```
x=[2 5 8];
w=max(x)
[~,loc] = ismember(w,x)
```

Comment: The question refers to matrices, not single values